# Getting getrusage() to measure system time in C

Tags: c, time, systemtime, getrusage

I would like to measure the system time it takes to execute some code. To do this I know I would sandwich said code between two calls to getrusage(), but I get some unexpected results...

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct rusage usage;
  struct timeval start, end;
  int i, j, k = 0;

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
  start = usage.ru_stime;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    /* Double loop for more interesting results. */
    for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
      k += 20; 
    }
  }
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
  end = usage.ru_stime;

  printf("Started at: %ld.%lds\n", start.tv_sec, start.tv_usec);
  printf("Ended at: %ld.%lds\n", end.tv_sec, end.tv_usec);
  return 0;
}
```

I would hope that this produces two different numbers, but alas! After seeing my computer think for a second or two, this is the result:

```
Started at: 0.1999s
Ended at: 0.1999s
```

Am I not using getrusage() right? Why shouldn't these two numbers be different? If I am fundamentally wrong, is there another way to use getrusage() to measure the system time of some source code? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please observe that `tv_usec` are microseconds, so your  format should be `%lu.%06u`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the difference between "user" and "system" time.  Your example code is executing primarily in user-mode (ie, running your application code) while you are measuring, but "system" time is a measure of time spent executing in kernel-mode (ie, processing system calls).

`ru_stime` is the correct field to measure system time.  Your test application just happens not to accrue any such time between the two points you check.

Comment: Thank you! You explained this better than my professor could.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `usage.ru_utime`, which is user CPU time used, instead.

Comment: This indeed does give me more preferable results. However I am still obligated to find a working way to measure the system time of some code. What is the use of usage.ru_stime if it does not work?

Comment: If the program is designed to run under kernel mode, then use `ru_stime`.  Otherwise, use `ru_utime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use gprof. This will give give you the time taken by each function.
Install gprof and use these flags for compilation: `-pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage.`