# How to call system call from kernel?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm trying to invoke the `getrusage()` system call from kernel space, but I don't know how.

I read about getting the kernel export ([Can we call system call in kernel space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841327/can-we-call-system-call-in-kernel-space)), but I don't know what that is or how to use it. Could someone show me how to call a system call from the kernel in C?

Edit: The old title was for a draft of a question, sorry!

Comment: Your title is very different from your question - could you elaborate?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: You could check this thread, which appears to duplicate your question a bit: [getting-getrusage-to-measure-system-time-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509660/getting-getrusage-to-measure-system-time-in-c) You can also check documentations for `getrusage`, e.g [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

Comment: [`man syscall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)? The man page even includes sample code for making system calls. That said, wrapper functions are generally considered the preferred approach (e.g., calling the `getrusage(...)` function rather than making a direct syscall).

Comment: @SpencerD: `syscall` is for making system calls from user space.

Comment: Take a look in the file `kernel/sys.c`.  Search for "getrusage".  Those are the kernel functions that implement (among other things) the `getrusage` system call.  Since you're in the kernel, you should be able to just call any of those functions directly.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you for the clarification. +1

Answer (score 2):

> How to call system call from kernel?

You don't. It doesn't even make sense. It's like asking "How do I enter my house when I'm already inside my house?".

In the kernel there's a whole bunch of functions. Some of them are added to the system call table and some aren't; but if you're already in the kernel you can use them without caring if they were added to the system call table or not. Note that if you're writing a kernel module then it ends up being dynamic linking done when the module is loaded (a bit like the kernel is a shared library).

Comment: I wonder though - `getrusage` takes a pointer to a buffer to be filled in.  The corresponding function in the syscall table, `sys_getrusage` or whatever, is going to be expecting a pointer to userspace memory.  Will it still work, on all architectures, if you pass a pointer to kernel memory?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I have no idea how Linux does it. Myself (at least for 64-bit 80x86 where there's a huge number of registers); kernel would shove all the data into registers and return to user-space, and let the user-space library's `getrusage` code unpack the data from registers into the caller's buffer (so that the kernel doesn't have to do all the sanity checks/validation of the library function's caller's buffer). Linux is probably "more generic" though.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Of course if the kernel's internal `getrusage()` is only usable from user-space (e.g. uses a buffer from user-space) there might be a different function that obtains the data (e.g. a `getrusage_internal()` that doesn't do any checks on the buffer, which is called by `getrusage()` after it does the checks). Also; it's likely that  there's a "process structure" (for each process) that contains the same data, and all code in the kernel can access these structures directly (without bothering with any `getrusage()` wrapper bloat), so trying to use `getrusage()` is a mistake anyway.